# Trying to figure out a strange behavior using MVC 4 Custom Error Pages. Sometimes my custom error page is bypassed on a 404

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

For the most part my custom error page for a 404 error is getting called correctly. However, some url's skip past my custom error page and invoke the iis 404 error page instead. Why is this happening?

This is an MVC 4 project running on IIS 7.5

```
//This invokes my Custom 404 error page.
http://192.168.1.10/test1/test2/test3

//This bypasses my Custom 404 and invokes the iis 404 error page.
http://192.168.1.10/test1/test2/test3/test4

//Web.config
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="Error404" />
  </customErrors>
...

//Route
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Error404",
    url: "error404",
    defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "Error404" }
);

//Error Controller
public ActionResult Error404()
{
    Response.StatusCode = 404;
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't your redirect be "~/Error/Error404"?  As for an answer, I assume you do not have a route that takes 4 parameters...maybe it is tied to not matching a route based on signature vs no matching controller/action methods?

Comment: I actually have routes with 4 params. Here's an example of my galleries route: url: "galleries/{GalleryID}/{GalleryTitle}/{MediaID}/{MediaTitle}"

Comment: I have not run into this, but you may look into the route debugger or something like that to see if there are in fact any routing issues that may be causing this.  Walk through the decisions IIS makes to determine why it is changing its mind between the two examples.  Sorry to not be more help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I just went through this exercise myself and here's what I did.

1. Installed the Magical Unicorn Mvc Error Toolkit @ http://nuget.org/packages/MagicalUnicorn.MvcErrorToolkit/ (I used nuget)
2. Follow the setup instructions in the Read Me @ https://github.com/PureKrome/WorldDomination.Web.Mvc.ErrorHandling
3. Your (our) applications are failing for a very specific reason: **the incoming request is not matching ANY routes (including the "default" route) and is falling through to IIS for the error**.  What you need to do is add the following route at the very bottom of you RouteConfig.cs (for MVC4) underneath the "default" route:

   ```
       routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Catchall",
           url: "{*url}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "404" }
       );
   ```

What this will do is prevent execution from passing back into IIS with the error and allow your application one last chance to pop your 404.

An example url: http://yoursite.com/some/fake/route will hit your default route and 404 out as expected (assuming you don't have a Some controller with a Fake action that accepts a parameter Route).

Once you add one more url segment, such as http://yoursite.com/some/fake/route/die, you need the catch all to handle it.

The * in the in the route definition allows you to catch as many url segments as are entered without having to add one for every possible case (which is also impossible).  Keep in mind that this is a general case solution... you might have other routes (with more than 3 url segments) and might have to tweak it slightly (for example, those route declarations would need to be higher in the RouteConfig.cs than the catchall).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure either why your custom error seems to bypass sometimes, but let me show you what I did on my MVC4 website.

1st, I created a catch-all route in the `RouteCollection` in RouteConfig.cs:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "CatchAll",
   url: "{*catchall}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "Index", statusCode = 404, error = new HttpException(404, "Route not found via RouteConfig.") });
```

2nd, I've created a `Controller` named `Error`. It's only job is to handle the exceptions thrown in the website:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(int statusCode, Exception error)
        {
            ErrorViewModel vm = new ErrorViewModel();
            vm.CurrentException = error;
            vm.InnerException = error.InnerException ?? null;
            vm.StatusCode = statusCode;

            Response.StatusCode = statusCode;
            Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

            return View(vm);
        }
    }
```

I'm using the ErrorViewModel to show the detailed error in HTML source code.

3rd, in the `Global.asax`, I overrided the `Application_Error` method to catch every exceptions in the website, and process them via the `Error` controller made at step 1:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
            Server.ClearError();

            RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
            routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Error");
            routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index");
            routeData.Values.Add("error", exception);

            if (exception.GetType() == typeof(HttpException))
            {
                routeData.Values.Add("statusCode", ((HttpException)exception).GetHttpCode());
            }
            else
            {
                routeData.Values.Add("statusCode", 500);
            }

            IController controller = new ErrorController();
            controller.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
        }
```

That's it, I removed the CustomErrors node from the web.config.
Huge part of this answer was found on this [blog post](http://thirteendaysaweek.com/2012/09/25/custom-error-page-with-asp-net-mvc-4/).

The

> Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

is the key to override the IIS 404 page.

Hope it helps!

Comment: My own implementation uses `web.config`. I just added `Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;` to my controller. and it works fine.

Comment: Maybe, but with the above implementation, you get much more details than redirecting to the error page. And you can log the complete error  stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

This is project source, may be it help you some way https://github.com/13daysaweek/Mvc4CustomErrorPage

Comment: The links can get broken over time. Please write the content rather than the link to a post.